# What should be the order of specific conductance (κ) of floride, chloride and bromide ions?

Tags: electrochemistry, halides, conductivity

The equivalent conductance order is $\ce{Br-} > \ce{Cl-} > \ce{F-}$.

$$Λ = \frac{κ}{c},$$

so $Λ$ is proportional to specific conductance?

But in ion chromatography we get peak area where $\ce{F-} > \ce{Cl-} > \ce{Br-}$ (specific conductance, μS/cm) for the same concentration, let us say 1 ppm.

Why?

Comment: Are they of the same concentration? As without that knowledge, the order of the conductivity ( specific conductance ) is undefined.

Comment: yes sir. lets say 1ppm

Answer (score 3):

ppm is ambiguous quantity, it can be v/v, w/v,w/w,n/n.

By other words, all 1 ppm very probably is not the same molar concentration, unless it is n/n ppm, relating itself to the molar amount of the solution.

$\Lambda = \kappa /c$ is correct, but $c$ must be the molar concentration.

$$\Lambda[\pu{Sm^2mol^-1}]=\frac{M[\pu{g/mol}]}{c[\pu{ppm as g/m^3}]}\cdot \kappa[\pu{S/m}]$$

Comment: Thank u sir. I missed the conc. unit.

Comment: @ggs Please don't post a "thank you" as a comment. Instead, [upvote](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) and/or [accept](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) answers that were useful to you.